# Не отрисовывается компонента после Context.API

Tags: reactjs

Убрал props'ы и решил добавить в свой проект Context.API. После этого перестала отрисовываться компонента

```js
// Файл с контекстом
import React from "react"

const StoreContext = React.createContext(null)
export default StoreContext
```

```js
// Файл с провайдером
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import StoreContext from './StoreContext.js';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import store from './redux/redux-store.js';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));


let renderEntireTree = (state) => {

  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
<StoreContext.Provider value={store} >
      <App/>
      </StoreContext.Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
renderEntireTree(store.getState())
store.subscribe(() =>{
  let state = store.getState()
  renderEntireTree(state)
})
```

```js
// Файл получатель провайдера
import React from "react"
import {addPostActionCreator, updateNewPostActionCreator} from "../../../redux/store"
import Myposts from "./Myposts"
import storeContext from "../../../StoreContext"
const MypostsСontainer = (props) => {

   

<storeContext.Consumer> 

   { store => {
        let state = store.getState()
        let newPostElement = React.createRef();
        let addPost = () => {
          
            store.dispatch(addPostActionCreator())
         
        }
    let onPostChange = (text) => {
       
       let action = updateNewPostActionCreator(text)
       store.dispatch(action);
    }
      return  <Myposts profilePage={state.profilePage} post={state.state} 
        postCount={state.postCount}  updateNewPostActionCreator={onPostChange} addPost={addPost} />

        
    }
    }

 </storeContext.Consumer>
    
    
}

export default MypostsСontainer
```

Comment: В консоли браузера есть ошибки?

Comment: Ошибок нету и warning тоже нету

Comment: зайди в App и удали все что там есть добавь простой 'div' с 123 и глянь в браузере

Comment: в редакторе тоже нету ошибок в терминале?